# Meaning of "Unless of the 'baby', thank you!"

Tags: meaning

I heard this dialogue in a drama:

> Tom: Let me introduce my baby brother, Jack.
>   Jack: Unless of the 'baby', thank you!

I wonder what does *'unless of'* mean there? Or it is actually *'unless off'*?
I've checked a dictionary and haven't found such an expression.

Answer (score 19):

To add to Shoe's answer, perhaps it was:

> "Uh, less of the baby, thank you."

And "less of..." is like saying "there is too much of...". As used in this expression, "*the* baby" means "talking about / saying 'baby'". (He is not referring to any actual baby.)

Jack is telling Tom, "Please stop calling me your 'baby' brother."

Answer (score 11):

I believe it is a mistranscription of

> And less of the 'baby', thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It should be *Less of the baby, thank you*. You use the expression "Less of the .. " to signal disagreement with what you have just heard. Here it means something like: *Hey, I'm not a baby any more.*

Comment: +1 By the way is it possible *Except for baby, thank you!* and what is the difference.

Comment: *Except for baby, thank you* does not work in this context. You could say: *Except I'm not a baby* or something similar, but this would tend to remove the jokey nature of the original expression.